# Android Studio1.0.0 update to 1.0.1 on Mac os has error

Tags: macos, android-studio

now I have one problem about updating Android studio 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 .

1. my Mac os system is 10.10.1
2. JDK version 1.7

the error info is

> some conflicts were found in the installation area.
> some of the conflicts below do not have a solution ,so the patch cannot be applied.
> press cancel to exit.
>
> file "Contents/MacOS/studio.x86_64"validate
>
> file "Contents/MacOS/studio"update

thanks for your regards!

Comment: In the worst case scenario, delete Android Studio 1.0.0 and install 1.0.1 anew. You'll retain all your program settings.

Comment: can I still retain the program setting and project ?