# Android Studio Update: Some conflicts found in installation area (studio.exe | uninstall.exe)

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

When I start Android Studio, it shows popup regarding new update of 1.1 release. But when I start updating, After downloading all patch files, while restarting, it shows following error:

[image]

I searched almost everywhere on Google and Stackoverflow. There are already two questions on so: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307952/some-conflicts-were-found-in-the-installtion-area) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547271/android-studio1-0-0-update-to-1-0-1-on-mac-os-has-error). But none of them are have any correct answer. I also tried running as administrator, restarting PC, turning off the firewall, uninstalling antivirus. But none of them worked.

I am using windows 7 32-bit. How to solve this problem? Can anyone help?

Comment: The dialog says that these two files were modified. Did you touch them somehow, or do you have some sort of antivirus (or a virus!) that modified them? The only solution may be a clean reinstall.

Comment: @No I never touched them before. I use avast as my antivirus and it isn't possible that virus attacked those files. I didn't have this kind of issue previously. And also there are many people on the internet talking about this issue. Shouldn't you guys fix it asap?

Comment: Although it is not a solution. You can download Android Studio without bulky SDK tools from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other. It is almost 200mb download

Comment: Same error on Linux. Trying to upgrade from 1.1.0 to 1.2.2.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html#3-0-0
As per release "macOS users: If you are updating an older version of Android Studio, you may encounter an update error dialog that says "Some conflicts were found in the installation area". Simply ignore this error and click Cancel to resume the installation.

"

Comment: Let's see, finally, nobody knows what is going on in the background ??::

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I know this is an older question but I encountered the same error while updating SDK components in Android Studio 2.3.3.   I was able to fix the problem by starting the SDK manager and un-checking the components that showed the error and clicked "Apply".  That un-installed just that component.  When it was finished, I re-checked the component and clicked "Apply" again.   When it was finished, the problematic component was updated to the newest version.  This was much quicker than doing a full un-install/re-install as stated in one of the solutions above.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue while updating the Intel System Images in Android Studio 2.3.3. This provided a quick fix.

Comment: In MacOS try: "cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/ && ls -la" in a terminal; check for the file/folder that is troubling the install process and delete it.

Comment: @zoccadoum How do you start the "SDK Manager?"

Comment: The SDK manager in Android Studio can now be found under the "Tools" menu (Studio version 3.5.2)

Comment: Didn't help me. Reinstall Android Studio on macOS much easier and faster.

Answer (score 31):

This is another option, it is not much easier than reinstalling but at least you don't have to worry about your settings getting lost

1. Go to help->about and note the version you currently have installed
2. Download zip file for your current version at https://developer.android.com/studio/archive
3. Manually overwrite conflicted files with files from zip
4. Update normally

Comment: This worked fine for me and someone on my team on Windows and Mac, we needed to recover the original copies of the JRE security policy files.

Comment: It would be better if you downloaded new version from https://developer.android.com/studio/archive and uninstall last version then install the new one.

Comment: It worked flawlessly! For me, the error seems to have appeared due to trying to fix this error with JRE/JDK: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/265713286
However, after being able to update I had to reapply again the fix to the issue, which might break the next update again…

Answer (score 14):

I hade same on Android Studio Electric Eel Patch 1

> Android Studio Update: Some conflicts found in installation area

but with **uninstall.exe**. I just deleted that file from android studio directory and updated successfully.

Comment: Honestly sounded like an odd solution to delete the uninstaller manually, but it work!!, Thank you

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem on some other files and could not figure it out.

You should download the last [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other) version and remove the old one.

Comment: I think it should have some other solution. Wait if anyone have answer.

Comment: I was also looking/waiting for a fix but it is just faster to download the newest version. That worked for me.

Comment: its not a real solution.

Comment: @Suragch  Do you recommend completely uninstalling the previous version before installing the newer version?  Or just add/install the newer version?

Comment: @AJW, I use the Ubuntu Linux version so I didn't have to uninstall anything, though I may have renamed the old folder to something else as a backup. I guess I just recommend the hacker's method: Just keep trying things until something works. I would definitely try Zoccadoum's answer below first.

Answer (score 12):

It appears like the only way to bypass this error and successfully update Android Studio is to **uninstall and reinstall it**.

- Before uninstalling, make a backup of your IDE settings through File | Export Settings.
- Download the "No SDK tools included" exe from [the Other Downloads section](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other). Avoid using download accelerators as they often mess up the downloads from https://dl.google.com .
- In the Install Wizard, you may uncheck to update AVD if you use Genymotion and don't need Google's Android emulator.

Comment: I followed these steps, but it was easier than mentioned. No need to uncheck anything, no SDK will be uninstalled. Also, no need to take any backup, it'll be done anyway.

Comment: You're right. They have removed the option to delete SDK from the uninstall wizard. It's much safer now. Also, no need to move the settings.jar backup from its default location. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Didn't work for me with Arch Linux, installed from AUR. Guess I'll have to wait for an update from AUR instead.

Answer (score 12):

Use the **JetBrains Toolbox** for Android Studio update, problem solved. No need to mess with the file permissions. Especially on company devices.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/download/ but it simply downloads the new version and deleted the old one automatically

Comment: @Vaiden, yeah, but it allows you to import everything from the old version to the new one. I don't know if I'm missing something here, but I think every custom config is imported

Comment: it doesn't recognize android studio!

Comment: Hi Elias, I think I experienced the same thing when installing the toolbox for the first time (long time ago). I had to download an Android Studio via toolbox first and then later updates were taken care of

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue on Ubuntu 18.04 when tried to update Android Studio from 3.4 to 3.5 version. I have changed Android Studio directory's ownership to my user:

`sudo chown -R <username> /opt/android-studio`

It resolved all but one errors for me, because I still had a `jre/bin/java - Access Denied` error, which I have resolved by killing its process:

```sh
# The second column of this command's output is PID.
ps -aux | grep /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java

kill <PID>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. It might also happen that you need to logout and and re login as `admin` user in your system.
2. Update the Android studio [in admin user].
3. Re login as a previous user.

Answer (score 2):

I had this symptom when updating from Android Studio 3.4.2 to 3.5.

In my case, the affected file was `plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/bin/kotlinc`.

The cause turned out to be that while the file's *contents* had not been modified at all... the *Unix permissions bits* on it had been.

Specifically, this was a file that comes as non-executable, and I had at some point chmod'd it to executable (because it should be) in order to use it from the command line.

The fix was to set those permissions bits back, with `chmod`:

```
$ chmod a-x /PATH/TO/android-studio/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/bin/*
```

This probably isn't a super common cause for this symptom, but hopefully it will be helpful to someone else. :-) I certainly didn't remember making that change, though once I spotted it I know exactly why I made it.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly my issue but with another property that I changed and needed to revert now :)

Answer (score 1):

You should check the **JDK Location** settings, which appears be changed on every Android Studio update, with commands *ctrl* + *Alt* + *Shift* + *S* (to reveal the *Project Structure* menu options, and **uncheck** the **Use embedded JDK** and find your current JDK Location, on windows machines, you can see that location on *environment variables* **JAVA_HOME**.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround, try deleting or moving the files that are causing the conflicts to another folder when the Update starts NOT BEFORE! That worked for me.

Comment: It shows absent error

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, but I face this issue almost every time I try to update my studio. Only solution I know which works for sure is clean install of studio....which is time consuming. So the solution is when you get to know the name of the file, search the location of that folder containing specified file. Check if that folder has lock icon on it, if it has then change the sharing settings to everyone and share the folder. If it does not have the lock icon on the folder check if it is in read-only mode. This worked for me hopefully someone finds this useful. 
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. What I did was to make sure of the whole folder's ownership. For some reason, some files where owned by root, so I changed it to my ownership. In linux you can use the followoing command on the Android Studio folder:

```
sudo chown yourusername:yourusername -R android-studio-folder
```

I just tried again and everything updated successfully. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The only solution worked for me is I have reinstalled Android Studio the latest version without uninstalling manually it and when starting the installer it asked me to uninstall and said that your settings will not be lost so I checked the uninstall and everything went smooth without any problems and got the latest version installed and all my settings the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can found the files in the android-sdk folder, and delete those files, and check your permission of the folder(android-sdk, build-tools, tools), if your can write, and download again.

I solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when upgrading from 3.1.x to 3.5.x. What worked for me was downloading the new Android Studio image from https://developer.android.com/studio and installing it (when asking me if I want to replace the old version I said yes). Everything seems to work fine now.

Comment: This has been suggested in a few of the other answers already, so I'm not sure why it needs posting again.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error when upgrading from 3.5 to 3.6, I managed to solve this without losing any sdk platforms and virtual machines in avd by installing the latest version of android,First Export the settings and then delete the two folders ".AndroidStudio3.x" in home directory and the "android-studio" in /usr/local or /opt directory, then  download the zip file of latest version of android studio and move the "android-studio" folder to /usr/local or /opt. Now run the /android-studio/bin/studio.sh and import the settings,Now Latest version will be installed.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was trying to upgrade Android Studio using a different user account to the account that installed Android Studio (the account had admin privileges).  When I switched to the account which installed Android Studio I was able to upgrade without this problem happening.

Answer (score 0):

I had also the issue with updating Android Studio on Windows. It did not update 2 jars. I looked for the files and they had the "read only" flag.

I unchecked "read only" and run the update again and it works.

Answer (score -1):

I have had a similar issue and solved it. Some documents were **encrypted** by the software installed on my PC, so updating to Android Studio 3.6 was not possible (in fact every update I have the same issue).

[image]

To solve it, just find those files in the Android Studio installation folder (probably Program Files/Android) and **decrypt** it. After that, you should be good to go. I hope it helps!

Comment: What do you mean by decrypting it?

Comment: I mean to decrypt it using the encryption software. In my case, the .doc file was encrypted  for protection using DRM.