# Android Studio error while updating to ver 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, updates, android-studio-3.0

I'm just trying to update my Android Studio from 3.0 to latest version 3.1 and I'm getting this strange error message:

[image]

I see from the answers of similar questions on SO that the common solution for this problem is reinstall the Android Studio. But maybe is there some other way to fix the update?

Comment: Don't upgrade it's buggy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587234/android-studio-update-some-conflicts-found-in-installation-area

Comment: @Ezio ahaha nothing new =) I am not surprised =)

Comment: make sure your older studio installation directory have jre folder there. It is for embedded JRE.