# Problems in updating Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

My current Andriod studio version is 3.0.1 and I am updating it to 3.1.2. I try to update android studio and the patch is downloaded successfully but its not getting installed and I get the following error window.

So eventually the Android studio version is not updated.

[image: Error message]

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45471627/4698320

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/28587234/6891563

Comment: @DäñishShärmà I tried some of the solutions from that page. Not working for me. I really don't want to uninstall my android studio. The most accepted answer tells us to uncheck the component that showed error in the SDK manager and then update. I don't have any such component which shows error in SDK manager.

Comment: @Khemraj Its a similar kind of error but if you compare both the screen shots there is difference in the problem column of both the screenshots. Also the files are different.

Comment: So that did not solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: Terrible!Every time when updating the heavy patches I forget the update is working and after me opens the AS it drops an  exception.  Then you have to download updates  again... OG, it s so ugly and inconvenient for ,e.g.,metered connection!

Comment: If the problem is *Access denied*, did you check the permissions on _android-studio/_ directory and sub-folders? On Linux, you could set: `sudo chmod -R 757 /opt/android-studio`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on some other files and could not figure it out.

You should download the last Android Studio version and remove the old one.