# "Some conflicts were found in the installation area" error when updating Android Studio to latest patch

Tags: android-studio

I am running Android Studio 2020.3.1, and while updating to 2020.3.1 Patch 1 I get this error:

[image]

It seems it is missing this file:

> Contents/jre/Contents/Home/Frameworks/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Versions/A/._JavaNativeFoundation.tbd

Is there a workaround I can use to fix this?

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587234/android-studio-update-some-conflicts-found-in-installation-area) can help.

Comment: Yes, deleting and reinstalling Android Studio gave me the latest version with Patch 1. Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I encountered the same issue. It indeed seems that `._JavaNativeFoundation.tbd` is missing in `Android Studio.app/Contents/...`. There's actually no need to delete Android Studio and reinstall again. I resolved it by downloading the latest Android Studio from the official website, and replacing the old `Android Studio.app` with the newly downloaded one (drag-and-drop/copy-paste).

Comment: Verified for macbook pro M1, this works for the error mentioned